# Why is this 1 reputation not added?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

Here is the reputation I earned today as shown in the reputation tab of my profile:

[image]

Yesterday, I had 20,289 rep, so adding the 61 that I earned today, it would be 20,350. However, my current rep is 20,349. The last 1 rep has not been added. Why not?

Apparently the last 1 rep was because an answer that I down voted on was deleted. Did I not get the rep because the answer is too old?

Note that I don't really care about this 1 rep change. I am just interested in how SO works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you'd already gained the 1 reputation a long time ago. That answer was originally deleted on Apr 26, '16 and you regained the 1 reputation then. The answer was then undeleted and re-deleted today, which moved the +1 from the previous date to today because today is now the new deletion date. So technically you would have lost the 1 reputation again, and then gained the 1 reputation again. Thus your reputation didn't change from it.

Comment: If I lost it today and gained it today, wouldn't the reputation tab show that I got a net gain of 60 rep?

Comment: @Sweeper No. Reputation changes due to removal act differently than unvotes. When a post is undeleted, the system just deletes the old removal event from the history, like the post had never been deleted ever. If it gets subsequently deleted again, it just adds a new removal event.

Comment: Consequently, then, the GUI is lying. No?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Sure, if you consider rep changes due to deletion/undeletion cycles to actually be *important*. We don't, and preserving reputation events from cycles like this is just too much work for almost no gain at all. We wouldn't be able to just look at the deletion state of a post; we'd have to look through the *history* of every post which is frankly never gonna happen.

Comment: Whether the data is important or not is entirely orthogonal to whether it is accurate.

Comment: (I'm not necessarily saying this needs to be fixed)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition But that's the thing - it's not *lying*, it's just not including useless information that doesn't matter. How does an extra removed and unremoved event in the history make it *any more* accurate?

Comment: It is lying if you got -1 then +1 but, on a count of what happened to your rep today, only the +1 is reported. It's literally an off-by-one error... hence this question. That's lying. (Though, again, I'm not saying we need to care that it is :P)